# Why Pointerproperty bpy.types.NodeSocket() work?

Tags: python, node-editor

I was trying a pointerpropery tied to the node socket, and I'm noticing that it seems to work, but this is weird, as Blender should only support `bpy.types.ID`, but in this list the `bpy.types.NodeSocket` doesn't seem to be mentioned: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=bpy%20types%20id#bpy.types.ID

This is very strange (For me), and I don't understand if it has always worked or is it new.
It would be very useful to me, but I don't understand if it will actually always be or was always supported.

Example about use into Addon:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

bl_info = {
    "name": "Prop Test",
    "author": "Noob Cat",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "location": "Text Editor",
    "description": "Script tools",
    "category": "Text Editor"}

class TestClass(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bool_test: BoolProperty(default=False) 

def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(TestClass) 
    bpy.types.NodeSocket.test = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=TestClass)
    
def unregister():
   
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestClass)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To test it into console:

Add mesh object , add a new material, and get a node (Principled Bsdf in this case):

```
>>> bsdf = C.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
>>> bsdf.inputs[0].test.bool_test = True
>>> bsdf.inputs[0].test.bool_test
True
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of  using `PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.NodeSocket)`?  (Bones and PoseBones are also exceptions to the ID rule)

Comment: Hello @batFINGER I made a ready-to-use example, it seems to work wonders.

Comment: Oh Ok, different. As long as ID properties are supported (eg `nodesocket["Foo"] = 3`) can use as above. Like with Bones and PoseBones.

Comment: @batFINGER Based on your experience, is it risky to write an addon with this pointerproperty?

Comment: Never done it. Don't  foresee any major issue using a fixed type pointer property on any objects on which can save an ID prop.  `D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs[0]['test'].to_dict()  >>> 
{'bool_test': 1}`